# Service Timing Out

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have a Web Service that receives information  in my project that the client address is pointing to:
http://Server/PaymentWCF/Service.svc?WSDL

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
foreach (Record rc in ListOne)
{
   client.RecordInsert(rc);
}
foreach (Record rc in ListTwo)
{
   client.RecordInsert(rc);
}
client.Close();
```

There are times when we have the ServiceClient open for awhile since we have many records to process.  (Up to 3,000)  Last night, I received the following error message:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:04:59.9374976. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

However, the bindings do not have any value of 00:04:59 anywhere:

```
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
                textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
```

Would it work if we open and closed the connection every 1,000 records? The client would not time out since it won't be open long.  We have normal operation when we process 1000-15000 records. But when we have upwards to 3,000 is where we start seeing the timeout.

How would you suggest I go about doing this?

Comment: _"However, the bindings do not have any value of 00:04:59 anywhere"_ The timeouts are approximate, it'll be set to 5 minutes somewhere.

Comment: How are you hosting this service?  I'm guessing IIS?  Which version?

Comment: Also, check the config settings on both sides - the client and the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your IIS settings?

Comment: Where would these settings be at in IIS? (Windows Server 2008)

Comment: Could this answer be expanded to include what the actual solution was?